# Posting an Asana task using fetch

Tags: asana, asana-api

I'm trying to work with the Asana API as I learn React and Redux. I've been able to get data from the Asana API using fetch() just fine so far, but I'm having trouble posting a task.

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
const options = (type, data) => {
  const defaultHeaders = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        'Asana-Fast-Api': 'true',
      }
  switch(type) {
    case 'get':
      return {
        headers: defaultHeaders,
      }
    case 'post':
      const body = JSON.stringify(data)
      console.log(body);
      return {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: defaultHeaders,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        body: body,
      }
    default:
      return {
        headers: defaultHeaders,
      }
    }
};

const asanaUrl = (props) => {
  const numOfProps = props.length;
  switch (numOfProps) {
    case 3:
      return `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/${props[0]}/${props[1]}?${props[2]}`
    case 2:
      return `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/${props[0]}?${props[1]}`
    case 1:
      return `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/${props[0]}`
    default:
      return console.log(props)
  }
}

export const asanaPost = (props, data) => {
  return fetch(asanaUrl(props), options('post', data))
    .then(response => response.json() )
}
```

In the console, I see the return from the console.log which shows the JSON I'm sending into my body key:

`{"assignee":22800770039251,"name":"test","notes":"test"}`

and the following error

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

The URL appears to be correct: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?workspace=31542879721131

The error message is:

`"Must specify exactly one of project, tag, or assignee + workspace"`

It doesn't seem to matter what fields I include in the body (including a project resulted in the same error), which makes me suspect that something else is afoot and the Asana API isn't getting a hold of the body or isn't able to interpret it with how I've set things up.

Thanks for helping me out with this!

Answer (score 1):

The api url I use is 
`https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?opt_fields=html_notes`

I also pass `projects` as a key and a string value in the body.

I do not use `'Asana-Fast-Api': 'true'` in the headers